# Why is calling fork via JNA in Java unreliable?

Tags: java, linux, bash, jna

I have my own terminal app written in Java and it works sometimes.  To use bash on Linux you have to create a pty, fork and exec bash with the pty assigned to it's stdin/out/err.  I've done this using JNA in a few different ways but nothing is reliable.  About 30% of the time the child process has problems and hangs.  I have to kill the process.  I've heard a lot about fork problems in Java, is there something I need to do?  When it fails I will see the message "child process started" but some point after that before it calls execvpe it stops.  It is not using 100% cpu, I have no idea what it is doing.  I've looked at JPty and similar projects and they seem to do the same.  Are they reliable?

Here is my code using forkpty()

```
  private boolean fork_pty(String cmd, String args[], String env[]) {
    IntByReference masterRef = new IntByReference();
    pid = util.forkpty(masterRef, null, null, null);
    if (pid == 0) {
      System.out.println("child process started");
      //child process (slave)
      c.execvpe(cmd, args, env);  //searches path for cmd
      System.exit(0);  //should not happen
    }
    //parent process (master)
    master = masterRef.getValue();
    new Thread() {
      public void run() {
        c.waitpid(pid, new IntByReference(), 0);
        close();
      }
    }.start();
    return true;
  }
```

Any ideas?  What if I forked before AWT is started, might that help?  Could the gc be an issue???

Comment: I used gdb -p PID to attach to the hung process and I found it is in pthread_cond_wait() calling from libjvm.so.  So it looks like Java is in some sort of deadlock.  Without debug symbols it's hard to see why.

Comment: Get rid of `System.out.println("child process started");` JVMs aren't designed to be forked. Don't use the JVM any further once you're in the child process.

Comment: I added the System.out.println() because it wasn't working in the first place, which doesn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.  Instead of fork()ing I use ProcessBuilder to fork() for me.  I tried using ProcessBuilder to exec bash directly using redirectInput/Output/Error to the slave pty but then I couldn't call setsid() and bash was messed up.  Then I used ProcessBuilder to exec another java function that completed the child end of the process which sets up stdin/out/err and then uses c.execvpe to run bash and that works every time.
Full source will be available in JavaForce/7.35 @ javaforce.sourceforge.net (see javaforce.jna.LnxPty)

-1 to those who thought it could not be done :-P

Here is my fork function:

```
  private boolean fork_nofork(String cmd, String args[], String env[]) {
    JFLog.log("fork:no fork version");
    String slaveName;
    master = c.posix_openpt(O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
    if (master == -1) return false;
    slaveName = c.ptsname(master);
    if (slaveName == null) {
      JFLog.log("LnxPty:slave pty == null");
      return false;
    }
    if (c.grantpt(master) != 0) {
      JFLog.log("LnxPty:grantpt() failed");
      return false;
    }
    if (c.unlockpt(master) != 0) {
      JFLog.log("LnxPty:unlockpt() failed");
      return false;
    }

    ArrayList<String> cmdline = new ArrayList<String>();
    cmdline.add("java");
    cmdline.add("-cp");
    cmdline.add("/usr/share/java/javaforce.jar:/usr/share/java/jna.jar");
    cmdline.add("javaforce.jna.LnxPty");
    cmdline.add(slaveName);
    cmdline.add(cmd);
    cmdline.add("" + (args.length-1));  //# args
    for(int a=0;a<args.length;a++) {
      if (args[a] == null) break;
      cmdline.add(args[a]);
    }
    for(int a=0;a<env.length;a++) {
      if (env[a] == null) break;
      cmdline.add(env[a]);
    }
    String cl[] = cmdline.toArray(new String[0]);
    try {
      ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cl);
      pb.directory(new File("/home/" + System.getenv("USER")));
      p = pb.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      JFLog.log(e);
      return false;
    }

    writeBuf = Native.malloc(1024);
    readBuf = Native.malloc(1024);
    new Thread() {
      public void run() {
        try {p.waitFor();} catch (Exception e) {}
        close();
      }
    }.start();
    return true;
  }
```

And here is the main() function that runs in the child process:

```
  /** This becomes the child process. */
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    if (args == null || args.length < 3) {
      System.out.println("Usage : LnxPty slaveName, cmd, #args, [args...], [env...]");
      return;
    }
    init();

    String slaveName = args[0];
    String cmd = args[1];
    int noArgs = JF.atoi(args[2]);
    int p = 3;
    ArrayList<String> process_args = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> process_env = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int a=0;a<noArgs;a++) {
      process_args.add(args[p++]);
    }
    while (p < args.length) {
      process_env.add(args[p++]);
    }

    termios attrs = new termios();

    try {
      int slave = c.open(slaveName, O_RDWR);  //should open this in child process
      if (slave == -1) {
        System.out.println("LnxPty:unable to open slave pty");
        System.exit(0);
      }
      if (c.setsid() == -1) {
        System.out.println("LnxPty:unable to setsid");
        System.exit(0);
      }
      c.tcgetattr(slave, attrs);
      // Assume input is UTF-8; this allows character-erase to be correctly performed in cooked mode.
      attrs.c_iflag |= IUTF8;
      // Humans don't need XON/XOFF flow control of output, and it only serves to confuse those who accidentally hit ^S or ^Q, so turn it off.
      attrs.c_iflag &= ~IXON;
      // ???
      attrs.c_cc[VERASE] = 127;
      c.tcsetattr(slave, TCSANOW, attrs);
      c.dup2(slave, STDIN_FILENO);
      c.dup2(slave, STDOUT_FILENO);
      c.dup2(slave, STDERR_FILENO);
      c.signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
      c.signal(SIGQUIT, SIG_DFL);
      c.signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_DFL);
      c.execvpe(cmd, process_args.toArray(new String[0]), process_env.toArray(new String[0]));
      System.exit(0);  //should not happen
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(0);
    }
  }
```

Comment: there's a setsid command, so it can be implemented with pure bash script.

Comment: val pb: ProcessBuilder = ProcessBuilder("setsid", "sh", "-c", "exec <" + child_pts_name + " &>" + child_pts_name + "; exec sh -i")